# I can just use snippets from all.snippets

Tags: vim

It seems that I can't use snippets from *.snippets files except all.snippets.

For example I can not use snippets from c.snippets or python.snippets.

If i try to define a custom snippets in all.snippets it works but not in c.snippets when I create a .c file.

But if I add the command on vim: `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes types` it takes the types into account.

Why it doesn't take the type in account?

Comment: You have a problem with a Vim plugin: try its issue tracker.

Comment: Do you have `:filetype [...] plugin on` in your `.vimrc`, i.e. does your filetype detection work?

Comment: @IngoKarkat: have `filetype plugin indent on` in .vimrc . I installed https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim before.

Comment: SPF13 changes so many things in so many unintuitive ways and installs so many plugins that it's near impossible to help you further. Drop that crap ASAP and do your configuration yourself: that's how it's supposed to be done.

Comment: I agree with @romainl: Drop your big SPF13 distro and stick with your `.vimrc`; should the problem persist, it's one for the issue tracker, but I'd also bet it's due to the heavy changes of the distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking here https://answers.launchpad.net/ultisnips/+question/236140, it seems that scripts from ftdetect are not properly run.
I have to copy UltiSnips.vim into ~/vim/ftdetect repository.

Comment: That's not a solution, that's a poor workaround that completely destroys any benefit of using a plugin manager in the fist place. Either it's the ultisnips guy's responsibility to fix his plugin or it's vundle's or spf's... see the mess you are in when you use so many 3rd party tools on top of others?